# Laravel 5.2 route Not working with error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have been using Laravel version 4.2. Yesterday, I installed Laravel 5.2 and now I have a problem with routing :

All routes not working only "/"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcZSg.png)

Comment: Might help if we see how your routes file is looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put index.php infront of your route name.
example:
bk/state this is a route name you need to change bk/index.php/state